# Simulating the path for Interest Rate

Tags: short-rate, overnight-rate

There are many ways to short term rates like `Ho-lee` process, `HW` process. However I failed to understand how this information can be used to simulate the process for Overnight rate like `EONIA` etc.

Can you please refer to any online technical papers to simulate such Overnight process?

Just to explain more, let say I define a HW process as follows

$dr(t) = (\theta(t)-\alpha r(t))dt+\sigma dW_t$

With this process, I can estimate a discount bond as $P(t, t+1)$ based on the estimated parameters (refer to [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hull–White_model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hull%E2%80%93White_model))

So is it right to day that the process for OI rate is just the process for $P(t,t+1)$?

Is there any software implementation like `R/Python` that someone can please refer to?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is very common to associate a short rate with the overnight rate like `EONIA` as it is, after all, very short -- 1 day. So any paper/implementation for a short rate model can be used as is.

Comment: @piterbarg - I have modified my original post with more information. Do you think I am going to right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path but here $P(t,t+1)$ is not your overnight rate but a daily discount factor. To convert to a simply compounded daily rate, which would be your overnight rate, you would do something like this
$$
R(t,t+1) = (1 - P(t,t+1))/(\tau P(t,t+1))
$$

Here $\tau$ is your daycount fraction for $1$ day

As I mentioned in the comment $R(t,t+1)$ is very close to the short rate $r(t)$ and, depending on the intended application, you might want to use the latter as it is a bit simpler. Otherwise use $R$